# how to select alternate rows from mysql using php

Tags: php

I want to select rows alternatively in mysql using php,

```
<?php
$result=mysql_query("select * from marker1 where  date='$maxdate' and time BETWEEN '$mintime' AND '$maxtime' and imei_no='$vehicle_imei_no1'")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

this is my query but it select all rows, in database i m not getting serialy data so i can't use this query

```
select t.id, name
from (select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as srNo from Employee) t
where (t.srNo % 2) = 1
```

i only differentiate by time '11:05:30' in this formate 
please guide me how to use query for alternative rows.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work!:

select * from marker1 where  date='$maxdate' and time BETWEEN '$mintime' AND '$maxtime' and imei_no='$vehicle_imei_no1'
AND (marker1.ID % 2) == 0

marker1.ID is the primary key and I'm supposing it as auto_increment.

This should select only the even values.

Comment: but whatever data i got for particular imei no it not serially because no of imei no's  data update simultaneously in same table

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10";
```

It would start from record 15th and return 10 records.

Ref: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Comment: Good thinking RaV, I couldn't understand the question. :-)